# Website/domain being blocked by google in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, cross-domain

Since few days we are experiencing an issue in one of our a domain named "id-validation.us".
Google is blocking this domain on browsing from google-chrome. We tried to rectify the issue and found that google blocking all hits which is being done to id-validation.us. We are using a wildcard certificate on this domain and certificate is fine as it is working well on rest of the domain. We tried to remove the code from a web server as well but the result is still same.

Google is throwing below error once you browse the website from google-chrome. Currently, an index.html file is placed on this web-server for this domain but the response is same.
error message[image]

Can someone help me find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You may have some automated script that may affect the computer or browser settings. Google recognizes any automatic redirection or setting-changing code in a server/website as malware.